# How would I write a metaclass, "Place", which can be used to define classes Region, State, and City?

Tags: python, metaclass

I am basically trying to accomplish the following, but with a metaclass.

```
class Region():
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

class State():
  def __init__(self, name, region):
    self.name = name

class City():
  def __init__(self, name, state):
    self.name = name
    self.state = state
```

Comment: Why would you use a metaclass here? What would be it's *purpose*? It looks like you might want some class to serve as a *base class* to these other classes, but a metaclass doesn't make any sense here, unless you elaborate

Comment: There are many ways this might be accomplished without using classes. I know how to do it with a base class. Why would I want to do it this way? That is a separate question. All I'm looking for here is an option that uses metaclasses.

Comment: *but that isn't really a clear question*. Why would you *want* to use a metaclass here? There is no obvious application, so it would really help if you were explicit about what you are expecting. Which isn't even clear. Here's a way that uses a metaclass, use `class Meta(type): pass`, then simply write `metaclass=Meta` in all your class definition statements... boom, you've used a metaclass.

Comment: I am creating a module. The user may decide to specify a location schema as, {region, state, city, store}, or some other arrangement. Once you have a list of regions, for instance, {ne, nw, se, sw, mw}, you can enter some states, each of which will go into a particular region. Given a list of states, you can then list the cities, etc. Each of these locations must be instances of a corresponding class, because they have some other values associated with them.

Comment: Ok, you clarified it, and still looks like a case for OOP as usual, with no need for metaclasses.If you prefer to list your schema, and hava mutable one - like in this example, you can use ordinary classes and dynamic creation of the classes by calling plain "type" (then, yes, you are using metaclasses) in that case you'd need a smart factory for given a schema create a set of classes with the proper associations for you. Is that what you want?

Comment: I would like for the user to enter something such as:

add_place region - 
region NW() - 
add_place state - 
state maine('NW') - 

It seems like I'm getting a lot of feedback, as to how I ought to approach this problem. I know how to write a function to add 2 + 3. Actually writing such a function would be silly, but it makes sense, if you're trying to demonstrate how to define a function. I'm sure there are many other ways this problem might be approached, but I'm only interested in this one approach for now.